# SQL Query using INSERT INTO...SELECT and ON DUPLICATE UPDATE (codeigniter 3.x)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm currently creating a little tool for logs and i have an hard time working with mysql tables.

Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE site_logs
(
    id       int auto_increment,
    level    VARCHAR(45),
    severity varchar(45),
    uri      varchar(255),
    message  VARCHAR(255),
    trace    varchar(255),
    device   varchar(45),
    os       varchar(45),
    browser  varchar(45),
    ip       varchar(45),
    created_ at datetime
);

CREATE TABLE site_logs_stats
(
    id int auto_increment,
    log_id int,
    date datetime,
    count int,

);
```

Here is the situation: Every hour i parse my logs file and retrieve an $result array where i got each error and the number of occurences during the hour.

Next I insert the values in a table like this :

```
$result = array_values($result);
            foreach ($result as $res) {

                $this->db->insert('site_logs',array(
                    'level' => $res['level'],
                    'severity' => $res['severity'],
                    'uri' => $res['uri'],
                    'message' => $res['short_message'],
                    'trace' => $res['short_trace'],
                    'device' => $res['device'],
                    'os' => $res['os'],
                    'browser' => $res['browser'],
                    'ip' => $res['ip']
            ));
```

What I want to do:

In the site_logs table i only want unique errors (if there is the same error a 14:00 and 16:00 i want it to be writen one time in this table). If the error got the same level, severity, uri and trace then i considere this is the same error.

In the second table i the history of each unique error ex: if the same error appears at 14:00 and at 16:00 i want to have the site_logs.log_id 2 times, the hours they're writen and the number of occurence during the slot ( ex 14:00 -> 15:00 and 15:00-> 16:00).

I tried a lot of different queries but failed.

EDIT:

This is now how i insert datas in site_logs table:

```
$result = array_values($result);
            foreach ($result as $res) {
                $this->db->replace('site_logs',array(
                    'level' => $res['level'],
                    'severity' => $res['severity'],
                    'uri' => $res['uri'],
                    'message' => $res['short_message'],
                    'trace' => $res['short_trace'],

            ));
```

with unique key on ID, it seems to work pretty well, i've deleted other fields for an easier sorting and avoid duplicated except by ip/ browser etc...
So now i work on the second part where i must insert site_logs.id in site_log_stats and count occurence each hours. (i'm thinking about 'last_insert' or something like this.

Comment: I think its important to first understand what would make two errors at 14:00 and 16:00 "non-unique". Is it that their severity level is the same and the message is similar? is it that the severity level is the same, the message is similar, and the device/os/browser/ip is the same etc. Reason for asking is for people to help create a query this information is curcial for deciding how it would need to be written.

Comment: Hello, finally i've deleted several parameters because of what you said about ip, browser etc. I've found how to insert logs in my site_logs table (it will become a sort of library of encountered errors). i edit my first message to let show you the code
`